# Есть ли стандартная функция сложения словарей по ключам?

Tags: python, python-3.x, словари

Есть ли стандартный обработчик данного функционала? Или более быстрый функционал?

```
def summ_dict(*args):
    cash = {}
    for el_d in args:
        for key, val in el_d.items():
            if key not in cash:
                cash[key] = 0
            cash[key] += val
    return cash

d1 = {'B': 2, 'A': 3}
d2 = {'B': 2, 'A': 3, 'C': 10}

print(summ_dict(d1, d2))
```

Comment: Стандартной нет. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-combine-two-dictionary-adding-values-for-common-keys/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Конечно есть:

```
from collections import Counter

d1 = {'B': 2, 'A': 3}
d2 = {'B': 2, 'A': 3, 'C': 10}

d = Counter(d1) + Counter(d2)
print(dict(d))

{'B': 4, 'A': 6, 'C': 10}
```

Comment: точнее, в функции `summ_dict(*args)` будет `return dict(sum((Counter(d) for d in args), start=Counter()))`